# ctags multi-line C function prototypes

Tags: c, ctags, exuberant-ctags, uncrustify

Is there a way for ctags to handle multiline function prototypes in C?

I've searched around and the `--fields=+S` is supposed to do multiline prototypes, but I can't get it to work:

```
ctags -x --c-kinds=pf --fields=+S file
```

file:

```
int 
foo(int
    x, int y
    );
```

ctags only returns:

```
foo(int
```

(Note that the return type is also missing)

Ultimately I would like to get an output similar to

```
int foo(int x, int y);
```

or

```
int foo(int x, int y
```

is `--fields=+S` not the correct way?
Are there part of the ctags fields that I am missing?
Any pointers in general?

If there is not a way to do it in ctags, any recommended programs? (I'm currently looking at uncrustify)

Comment: The compiler is where this functionality *should* be.  It's done the preprocessing, it has the syntax tree and symbol table at hand.  It's 2018 and still this functionality, which was in DEC's compiler 20+ years ago (cc --proto foo.c > foo.h) isn't in gcc.  Absurd.  [You could even select just static or just extern functions and/or vars to produce a public and a private .h file!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find anything with ctags so I wrote a python script to re-arrange my file so that ctags could capture the prototypes.

Note: my code had comments and so much of this takes care with removing them (otherwise they would get in the way of ctags).

Manipulations were done in this order:

```
# concat to one line
file_str = ''
for line in read_from.readlines():
    file_str += line

# remove all /* */ comments
file_str = re.sub('/\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*/', '', file_str)

# remove '//' comments
file_str = re.sub('//.*', '', file_str)

# split on '\n'
file_as_list = file_str.splitlines(True)

# strip everything
for index in range(len(file_as_list)):
    file_as_list[index] = file_as_list[index].strip()

# add in newlines where appropriate
for line in file_as_list:
    # if the line ends in ';' or '}'
    if line.endswith(';') or line.endswith('}'):
        # append a newline to the stripped line
        write_to.write(line.strip() + '\n')
    else:
        # append a space to the stripped line
        write_to.write(line.strip() + ' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my code but I couldn't modify it. 
When I use the --fields=+S parameter, it seem to work because I get an additional line in the tag file. The signature: part contains all the parameters of the function.

CopyToTX26  D:\BiseL\My Dropbox\Work\0_BSW\PKG_CMD\Memory.c /^void CopyToTX26( uint16        memory_ID, uint32 ** pt_data_address, uint32  nb_recover, $/;" f   signature:( uint16 memory_ID, uint32 ** pt_data_address, uint32 nb_recover, uint32 * nb_copied, uint32 max_length )

Answer (score 1):

--_xformat option may help you.

```
[jet@localhost ~]$ cat /tmp/foo.h
int 
foo(int
    x, int y
    );
[jet@localhost ~]$ ~/var/ctags/ctags -x --c-kinds=pf --_xformat="%-16N %4n %-16F %C %S" /tmp/foo.h
foo                 2 /tmp/foo.h       foo(int (int x,int y)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove unneeded line breaks with a simple filter, e.g.

```
 tr '\n' ' '  | sed 's/\([{};]\)/\1\n/g'
```